# Reopen How to share a usb drive between laptops without a physical tether?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Can you re-open [Can I share a USB drive between laptops without a physical tether?](https://superuser.com/q/356714/101392)

I have referenced the model question in the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and revised my question to the [standard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/what-point-and-shoots-are-good-in-low-light-conditions).

I revised due to concerns as of Nov 11, 2011 11am pst.

Answer (score 2):

Your question mixes up a couple of reasons why it doesn't fit the site.

You're not entirely clear about what you mean in extending a USB over wireless. Is that a data transfer from the stick to another port? Adding more reach to the signal?

Being unclear puts your question in a vague state, enough for votes to close as "not a real question" (NARQ).

But then it tries to clarify itself in terms of a laundry list of features. This makes it a shopping question and off topic.

Could have gone either way, but the tally of final close votes sided with NARQ.

Comment: I have removed all the shopping list items.